# How to connect mySQL to SVG using RaphaelJS?

Tags: php, html, mysql, svg, raphael

I am trying to link a MySQL DB to an SVG image to dynamically change the SVG elements with Raphael JS.

I have a MySQL DB where I query using PHP and display the results in table form to an html page: (The script below works and displays the username and a picture only when the condition of the timestamp is met.)

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("","","");
    mysql_select_db("");
    $res=mysql_query("select username, picture from 'table' WHERE     status > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 300");
    echo "<table>";
    if (!$res) {
        die("Query to show fields failed");
    }

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($res);

echo "<h1>Table:Status</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";


for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($res);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>"; echo $row["username"]; echo "</td>";

echo "<td>"; ?> <img src=" <?php echo $row["picture"]; ?>" height="50">  

<?php
```

How can I take the similar concept above of displaying the results in table form to an SVG image where the SVG elements will change/update only when the query condition is met?

Here is my sample SVG image with 5 elements:

```
<polygon fill="#B2B2B2" points="150.3,8.8 203.8,31.7 169.8,91.4       133.4,75.8 "/>
<circle id="circleT3" circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="163.1" cy="53.6" r="7.3"/>
<circle id="circle3_1" circle fill="#CCCCCC" cx="184.5" cy="82.4" r="7.3"/>
<circle id="circle3_5" circle fill="#CCCCCC" cx="136.6" cy="27.2" r="7.3"/>
<circle id="circle3_4" circle fill="#CCCCCC" cx="166.4" cy="7.3" r="7.3"/>
```

Can someone point me to some sample code or tutorial? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

EDIT:

In MySQL DB I have a column for username, password and timestamp. When a user logs into webpage the timestamp updates. The PHP code above is used to query who has logged within 5 minutes ago from current time.

What I would like to do with this information with SVGs is create a graphical representation of the login.

So each username will have their own SVG element (a circle) associated with them and when they log in/out, that SVG element (code above) will change color.

Right now I do not know how to link the username with my SVG elements so the SVG element will dynamically update like my table I query from MySQL when the timestamp changes.

Comment: Its unclear what you will have in the database, markup or just attribute data or something ? Why do you need Raphael, why not just output the markup the same as you do with the html?

Comment: True I do not need Raphael. I basically just want to output the query in graphical format such as in SVG elements.

Comment: Trying to but I just started learning SVG and do not know how to connect the query output to the SVG elements.

Comment: Exactly the same as you have done with the html..just echo the svg markup and variables like you have done with the html & php.

Comment: For the HTML and PHP, I query the MySQL DB and echo the content that meet the query condition. Are you suggesting I create a new column in MySQL DB and add in the SVG markup and echo from PHP? Sorry it has been a long day and appreciate your help so far.

Comment: I have no idea whats in your database, and what svg you want to output from that data or why. So no one can really help until you tell them. I'd probably be tempted to put up a new question that has explains what data you have in the database and how it corresponds to svg.

Comment: Ian, I have updated my question above. Hopefully my question is more clear on what I hope to accomplish. I am unsure if anyone has done something like this before.

Comment: You may be better off with something like Snap (depending on if you need old browser support), where you could do something like Snap('#circle3_1').attr({ fill: 'green' }); depending on whether the svg is already on the page.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would I link each SVG element to the username to use snap? I looked at some snap.svg tutorials http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-transform-groups

Comment: Thats down to your design, you could give each circle an id of the username for example or whatever.

Comment: I see, so lets say a circle will have an id of user1. With the snap code above, that circle will change to green. That is good but now my question would be how to have that svg element appear when user1 is online per the query or disappear when user1 is offline? If not, the svg element will always be on the page and it will always be green.Sorry for being greedy with questions...

Comment: You have choices...either create/delete circles on the fly with javascript/Snap/Raphael(depends if its always a new page, or ajax type updates), or reuse some, change the css display:none, or opacity of it whatever.

Comment: I think I understanding this. So, for me wanting to have the circle in the same location in a table (office meeting layout with assigned seats) but change color when the user logs in or off using ajax update... I would need to query the html page to see if that username on the webpage and update the corresponding svg element accordingly? Would you recommend any other alternatives?

Comment: if by html page you mean some ajax query, probably in json format it would sound reasonable. If the username is already on the page, you don't need to do any ajax stuff, you could just query the dom for an html element with that name/id or something.

Comment: Well when the user logs on or off, the timestamp gets updated and that will change how many users are online. So table in html will only display active users. So I could say the username can already be on the page, I can just query the dom or convert the table data to json?

Comment: No need to convert to json, you could do something like.. if (document.getElementById('user1')) Snap('#user1image').attr({ fill: 'green' }); or similar. I would have a bash, and then ask a new question when stuck.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a JavaScript with bash if loops and use snap.svg to change the svg element. Last question, how can I rep you? You have been a big help, first time on stack overflow for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on further information that isn't really available until the rest is written.

You could combine Snap (to modify existing inline SVG or create it) or Raphael (to create new SVG only, you can't use it to modify inline SVG), or another SVG library of choice (eg svg.js or jquery.svg maybe).

Assuming you already have something to use on the page, that is showing the logged in user, you could do something like in pseudocode...

```
loop user; 
if( document.getElementById( userId ) ) Snap('#' + userId + '_image').attr({ fill: 'green' });
```

(The svg reference may be the same as the circles, but somewhere you would need some type of lookup to know which circle is which userid)

This assumes the svg is on the page. If its not, you could create it with

```
paper.circle(x,y,r).attr({ fill: 'green' });
```

If you want it dynamic (so status changes without a refresh), you may need to tie ajax calls to get status from the mysql db, but if you already have a user name displaying on the page, I'm assuming that is already taken care of.

Comment: Ian, I am having a little trouble with putting in my svg code (above) to work with snap.svg (it does not render). Also I cannot seem to get the if statement to change color of single svg element I created as a test with a word on the html page. I will continue to figure it out but any tips to speed things along is greatly welcomed.

Comment: Some of thats pseudocode...try getting a single circle to be displayed, check the console log in Chrome or whatever for any errors. Then if still stuck, try and get a very minimal case on a jsfiddle and post a new question maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully update the svg element color to when the user logs in, the corresponding circle will change color. So I have my svg code from illustrator. I then put in this script in my php file:

```
window.onload = function () {

if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('username') > -1){
         circle1_1.setAttribute("fill", "yellow");  
    };
    };
```

Whenever a user logs in, the info is populated on the table in the html from the MYSQL query and the script looks to see if that username is on the page and if it is, change color of SVG element.

So it basically links the SVG element to any value/variable.

Not the prettiest code or logic out there but for anyone else doing something similar, enjoy.